# Tool palette component

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Is there a component I can download or buy that looks and behaves like the Delphi IDE tool palette?

[image]

What I need is a component similar to this to display different items under different categories.

The items I want to populate it with are not components like TEdit, TButton etc but just regular list items which could be anything, and could have any custom icon.

Could anyone suggest or recommend me to any available components like this?

I am using Delphi XE.

Comment: It look like a particular case of [progressive disclosure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511487.aspx) for me.

Comment: Interesting link thanks for posting user539484

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What do you know I have discovered the component TCategoryButtons actually inside Delphi.

[image]

This seems to be the same type of component.